# Where is the best place to allocate memory to a variable that is used by a few of methods?

Tags: java, list, memory-management, arraylist, lazy-initialization

I have a class as following which is used to retrieve all users and all online users from database, after retrieval they put the results in "users" variable to be used by jsp.

I am wondering on which line should I have List  users = new ArrayList ? to consume less memory and to be efficient? Please note just two of methods use it.

*I know if I do not create it in constructor I would need to create it in all methods that going to use it, but as just two methods are using it does it make sense to create it in constructor? Please give me your reasoning, I want to learn.

```
public class Groups {
   private List<User> users;

   public Groups(){
       //Line 1 users = new ArrayList<User>;

  //Line 2 if (users == null) {
  //            users = new ArrayList<User>();
  //       }
  }

   public retrieveAllGrades(){
    ...
   }

   public retrieveAllUsers(){

        //Line 3 users = new ArrayList<User>;

         this method uses it to keep the results of all users retrieved from database
   }

   public retrieveOnlineUsers(){

    //Line 4 users = new ArrayList<User>;

      this method uses it to keep the results of all online users retrieved from database
   }

   all getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Right at declaration.

Comment: whats your reasoning?

Comment: How could it be right to assign a new list to `users` every time `retrieveAllUsers()` or `retrieveOnlineUsers()` was called? Any previous values would be lost on every method call.

Comment: because it will be retrieved from database, question is updated

Comment: Then why would you need it as a class field at all?

Comment: to use it in jsp to show the results

Comment: Then it's used in more places than in just those two methods?

Comment: it is used in jsp to be shown to user but just those two methods put data in it

Comment: @TedHopp question is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you want to allocate memory in the constructor so that it can be shared by methods, even if it is just two of them

If you are concened about memory, you can use `lazy` allocation and only allocate it if needed.  So you can start with users as `null`, but declare it as `null` in the constructor

Then if either method is called, you can check if it is `null` then you allocate (call to new).  Keep in mind this can cause more complications in multithreaded code and will cost you a bit of cpu everytime either method is called because you have to check for `null`

Example of lazy allocation:

```
public Groups(){
       users = null;
  }


   public retrieveAllUsers(){

        if (users == null) users = new ArrayList<User>;

         // this method uses it to keep the results of all users retrieved from database
   }

   public retrieveOnlineUsers(){

      if (users == null) users = new ArrayList<User>;

      // this method uses it to keep the results of all online users retrieved from database
   }
```

Comment: thanks but I do not get you, my question is that what would be an efficient way in general?

Comment: You beat me to it by 1 min :)

Comment: @J888 "In general you want to allocate memory in the constructor"  -- the lazy allocation is an advanced technique to be used once you have profiled you code and have weighed the space vs time trade-off.  It is most likely too early for you to do that yet.

Comment: thanks I have two questions would you please tell me how should be the code after implementing lazy allocation ? the other question is that do you know much about profiling ? I need to do that but not sure how

Comment: @J888 As far as profiling - that is too large a topic for a comment or even a question here.  In terms of code - look at the edits.

Comment: Just to clarify in this case if each method is called after the other it will not create a new one as users is not null but if class is just created the users is null and need to be created am I right ?

Comment: @J888 - so if you call either method 1 or more times memory will be allocated on on the first.  If neither is called than it stays null, and you save your memory.  If one or the other is ALWAYS called at least once - then do it in the constructor.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum question is updated , I have added few lines in constructor

Comment: @J888 The if check for null should never go in the constructor

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum the reason that I  have not accept the answer is that I've thought of a new idea so I added new lines to the constuctor and informed you

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum regarding profiling which software do you use ?

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum I am using struts2 do you think I would have any problem if I use this kind of lazy initialization ?

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum by the way as my application is a web app and multithread would it be an efficient method ?

Answer (score 1):

Constructor is the place where you should be doing this.

Putting it anywhere else might look little memory efficient to you for sometime but it'll have a big tradeoff over design. Suppose you allocate memory in retrieveOnlineUsers() but the how do you guarantee the order of operation on "users". If retrieveAllUsers() is called first without allocating memory and performing some tasks, you'll fall into NPE. At the time of writing you might guarantee that retrieveOnlineUsers() is always called first but in future somebody else looking at your code will never know that retrieveAllUsers() shouldn't be called first.

Constructor guarantees that no other method would be called before it and hence every function will have concrete definition of "users".

However, if you have decided NOT to initialize it in constructor, then keep a null check in methods which are going to access "users" and define it if it is NULL. Although, this is not the case here but mentioning it for future- In these situations of lazy initialization, you need to be extra careful if you are running in multi-threaded environment and your methods are static. It might create a race condition. There is a lot to it but not discussion as it'll go well beyond the complexity of the question asked.

Comment: I meant to have it in constructor only or in both methods not just retrieveOnlineUsers method

Comment: Then you can probably have a null check in both methods, and if its not defined, define it. Keep this check in both methods what I would say.

Comment: take a look at my answer to see how to avoid the timeing issue can be avoided and no NPE is emitted.  You do it in BOTH places.

Comment: if I put it in constuctor it means for sure it will be defined so it is impossible to find it null in either of methods right? so why should I check it against null value?

Comment: I meant, if you are NOT defining it in constructor then keep a null check.

Comment: if you wish to recommend lazy allocation - then you should update your answer to reflect that

Comment: I've added a new tag for that

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum I already did that. I'll be adding little more explanation to it.

Comment: @J888 - I meant this **answer** and for rajneesh2k10 to update it, but good job on tagging - I will +1 your question.

Comment: @rajneesh2k10 think about what you are adding beyond what was said in my answer and focus on that - making your answer match mine doesn't help visitors to this question

Comment: thanks , question is updated, I've added few lines in constructor

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum I never take it as reputation or earning credits as it seems from your comment. I didn't even read your answer completely. Its just unfortunate that we are in race condition for this answer.

Comment: @rajneesh2k10 I have a very funny question, does multithreading  problem occurs in java web applications?

Comment: @rajneesh2k10 - my comment reflects the fact that SO is a knowledge repository and it is everyones responsibility to keep it as clean as possible, I am not saying you are just in it for credit.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Thanks Glenn. I'm equally concerned about SO being healthy.

Comment: @rajneesh2k10 I am using struts2 do you think I would have any problem if I use this kind of lazy initialization then ?

Comment: @J888 I'm not much into WebDevelopment but a rough idea is to check how multithreading is implemented in your webserver. According the scenario you have given in the question, it's not a problem since the methods accessing "users" is not static. So multithreading is not a problem for you right now. :)